# Facebook Login SDK Configuration

Tags: facebook, configuration

I was adding details in the developer console, but the facebook app info not allowing the package name. "com.jewish.emoji.stickers.jmojis", it was saying one or more package name is invalid.

[image]

Did anyone knows why this is happening ?